# form c# inputs strings doesn't work well

Tags: c#

I did a form taking a string for input, but if this string is "T:\", the program take "T:\". So, this string I save in a variable "workShearch".

After this variable uses in:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, Regex.Escape(wordSearch), Regex.Escape(wordReplace));
```

But this line contain an error, because wordSearch in this case is "T:\", and the program trhow me an exception like that:

The error ir parsing "T:\" - illegal \ at end of pattern.

Thanks!

Ou! I have a solution! Is this!

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.Default);
writer.Write(content.Replace(wordSearch, wordReplace));
writer.Close();
```

Comment: use a verbatim @ , \ is a special case rather than having \\ which will work use String str = @"yourStringValue";

Comment: If I put this : content = Regex.Replace(content, @wordSearch, @wordReplace); The error is the same :S

Comment: And then I put string str = @wordSearch;
                      string str1 = @wordReplace; 
                      content = Regex.Replace(content, str, str1); And the error persist...

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape it twice since it is both a regex and C# escape character. "T:\\\\"

Comment: But where I escape that ?